# Cookies for Domain and its Subdomains in Node/ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cookies, subdomain

So what im attempting to do is to set a cookie on `domain.com` which is available to **all subdomains** `*.domain.com`. Im currently using Express 4.x and NodeJS.

At the moment I can set and get any Cookies on the main domain in my case its testing on a local environment via `lvh.me:3000` (allowing for local  subdomains)

This is bascially what my Express.js App looks like:

```
// Require all files (express,http,express-session,cookie-parser...)

var api = express()

// Cookie Parser 
api.use(cookieParser());
api.use(session({
    secret: 'yoursecret',
    cookie: {
        path: '/',
        domain: '.lvh.me:3000',
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 24, // 24 hours
    },
    resave: true, 
    saveUninitialized: true  
}));

// CORS
api.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
    next()
})

// View Engine
api.set('views', './api/views');
api.set('view engine', 'ejs');
api.disable('x-powered-by');

// Stylus
function compile(str, path) {
  return stylus(str).set('filename', path);
}

api.use(stylus.middleware({
  src: './app',
  compile: compile
}));

// Serving Static Content
api.use(express.static('./app'));

// All Routes 
require('../api/routes/test.server.routes.js')(api);

// Router
api.get('*', function(req, res) {
     //res.cookie('remember', 1, { domain : "lvh.me:3000" });
    res.render('index'); // Get all requests to Index. Angular takes over routing. 
});

// Return Application
return api;
```

Cookies are set via Cookie Parser `res.cookie('user', 'bobby');` which seem to be fine for going to `lvh.me:3000/anything` but for `boddy.lvh:3000/anything` the Cookies are empty.

Am I missing anything here, I thought Cookies would be available across all subdomains? I have read a few Articles/Posts on Stack Overflow but they all seem rather outdated. Any guidance or help is greatly appreciated.

On a side note if i set a cookie within express file it will be available through out the application. For Example:

```
// Router
api.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.cookie('user', 'jim'); // This can be accessed   
    res.render('index'); 
    // Get all requests to Index. Angular takes over routing. 
});
```

Any reason why? - This is in the most part because its being set on any/every view. So it still leaves me with the original question.

Answer (score 0):

While setting cookie if your domain name `mydomain.com` it is not accessible by subdomains. You have to put leading dot (e.g `.mydomain.com`). In that case cookie will be shared across subdomains

Comment: I understand the leading dot aspect, as this is already set with api.use() ? For which the url is lvh.me:3000 and i set the cookie domain as .lvh.me:3000, yet it doesn't seem to work across domain/subdomain. Any suggestions?